# mySQL query to find duplicate row

Tags: sql, duplicates, row

Exmaple:

```
[empid    date      bookid]
----------
1        5/6/2004   8

2        5/6/2004   8

1        5/7/2004   8

1        5/8/2004   6

3        5/8/2004   8

2        5/8/2004   7
```

In this table,I need to get empid 1 as output..since it has bookid 8 more than once..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to group by `empid`, `bookid`, AND `date`?  The meaning of date could be important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table
GROUP BY empid, bookid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But it will give you duplicates. If, for example, you have 1-8,1-8,1-9,1-9 you will get 1,1 as output because empid 1 has duplicate bookid's for two distinct bookid values. You will need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` to filter out the duplicate empid.

Comment: Alin Purcaru, Thanks for your ans..query works correct if i add distinct.. SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table GROUP BY empid, bookid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empid
from table
group by empid
having Count(distinct bookid) > 1
```

Comment: you select empid that has more than one distinct bookid, the question asks for empid with the same bookid more than once. your query would output 1 and 2, not just 1.