# MySQL check if value exist more than once

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database and a have a table named **CALLER**. In table caller I need to check if in column **USERNAME** there are values which exist more than once and if exist to list all these values.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862288/mysql-query-to-find-duplicate-row

Answer (score 20):

Ususlly you can do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`

```
SELECT USERNAME FROM CALLER
GROUP BY USERNAME 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Update: To get all duplicate rows:

```
SELECT * FROM CALLER WHERE USERNAME IN
  ( 
    SELECT USERNAME FROM CALLER
    GROUP BY USERNAME 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  )
```

Comment: Thank you all but can i list them like:                   test1@gmail.com                                                        test1@gmail.com                                                     test2@gmail.com

Comment: @Fi3n1k I've added updated query.

Comment: Note that the second query (to get the rows) can run really slow.

Comment: the second query is great and really useful

Answer (score 1):

Before getting to the answer....

It would have been a help if you'd provided the full table structure (as a CREATE TABLE statement)

If you need to apply this exercise it implies your database design is wrong - and after you've identified the duplicates and resolved them then you should add a unique index on the relevant column.

Assuming that you've got an auto-increment field, or some other value (such as created date) which differentiates between rows with the same USERNAME....

```
 SELECT a.id, username, b.id
 FROM caller a
 INNER JOIN caller b
 ON a.username=b.username
 AND b.id>a.id
```

Note that this will report some rows more than once if the username exists for more than 2 rows. Alternately:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(DISTINCT id), MIN(id), MAX(id)
FROM caller
GROUP BY username
HAVING count(*)>1
```

But this won't explicitly identify all the ids where there are more than 2 rows with a specific username.